# Call Java method in current instance of containing object's class

Tags: java, android, class

I have a main class as such, "Class A":

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mView = new AppGLSurfaceView(this); <------- I am creating 
    }

    // Log <--------------------------------------- our log function
    public void LogInfo(String message) {
        android.util.Log.i("MyLogTag", "Message:" + message);
    }
}
```

Class A contains an object of this class:

```
class AppGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public AppGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        mContext.LogInfo ("onTouchEvent"); <--------------- FAIL
        return false;
    }

    Context mContext;
}
```

Off hand, it looks MyActivity is passing a reference of itself to the 2nd class, mView = new AppGLSurfaceView(this) is passing.   "this" is the object reference, correct?

I am storing this object reference in class B in a variable via "mContext = context;"

How can I call the LogInfo method?

(I rarely use Java, so if it isn't method but rather a function, please briefly correctly me, I do want to know the Java terminology.)

Comment: a `Context` is a `Context`, not a `MyActivity`, there's no way for the compiler to know that in this code the context is a `MyActivity`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for letting me know this.

Comment: see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021690/180100)

Comment: @RC -- in my example above, Class B is not a subclass of Class A.  So the subclass/superclass thing doesn't apply to the best of my knowledge.  I'm not extending a class in the above.

Comment: In fact `Activity` extends [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LogInfo(....)` is a method of the `MyActivity` class, you are trying to call in on a `Context` object, you need to cast the `mContext` in order to do that, ex: `((MyActivity)mContext).LogInfo(....)`

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you are passing an instance of class `MyActivity` to constructor of class `AppGLSurfaceView`, you can call method on instance of `MyActivity` as:
`((MyActivity)mContext) .LogInfo()`

On a side note you should use camel case for methods in Java (`logInfo` and not `LogInfo`). Also you don't need to declare method static as you want to call method in current instance of containing object's class.

Answer (score 0):

Context is not an object of MainActivity, To use that function create its object or make that function as static in your MainActivity

```
public static void LogInfo(String message) {
    android.util.Log.i("MyLogTag", "Message:" + message);
}
```

and then in your A class  use like this

```
MainActivity.LogInfo ("onTouchEvent");
```

Comment: Is there a way to not have it be static?

Comment: @L-X To me it seems that OP wants to call method on current instance. Making it static will defeat the purpose.

Comment: @akhil_mittal can you explain what do you mean by "call method on current instance" what difference it will create

Comment: When a method is static it belongs to the class and not to a specific instance.

Comment: But all it will do is print on LogCat there will be no difference

Comment: Agree but the method is not invoked for the current instance. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the constructor of `AppGLSurfaceView` to

```
class AppGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    MyActivity myActivity;

    public AppGLSurfaceView(MyActivity myActivity) {
        super(myActivity);
        this.myActivity = myActivity
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
       myActivity.LogInfo ("onTouchEvent");
       return false;
    }
}
```

This introduces a dependency to `MyActivity`, so you can't create a `AppGLSurfaceView` anymore with any `Context`. Maybe you want to introduce an interface for logging.