# Child class method cannot be accessed when a child class object has a reference of parent type

Tags: java

Could not access methods from child class using the below line,

```
Parent p = new Child(); p.print();
```

Suppose I have a method `print()` inside Child class and the same method is **NOT** there in the Parent class. In this scenario we cannot access child class method `print()` using the above line of code. But note that if we have the same method `print()` in the parent class then we can access it using the above code.

There might not a real life scenario like this but trying to understand why I am not able to access child class `print()` using a child object which is of type Parent if we dont have the same method defined in the parent class.

Sample code is below:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Parent p = new Child();
        p.print(); //Compiler throws an error saying "cannot resolve print method".


    }

}

class Parent {
    int x = 10;


}

class Child extends Parent {

    void print(){
        System.out.println("Child");
    }

    int x = 20;
}
```

**EDIT :** Here , if I define the `print()` method inside the parent class then I can access the child class `print()` method using an object of type Parent. So I assume that we cannot say that an object of type parent can access only members/methods defined inside a parent class.

Also , I know that We can access the child method by casting the parent type to the child type. I am wondering how we can access the child class method without casting but if we define the same method in the parent class as well.

I have edited the question so as to make sure that this has no relation with the other question - [Calling a subclass method from superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021603/calling-a-subclass-method-from-superclass)

Comment: @Jim Garrison ... I have edited the question so as to make sure that this has no relation with the other question -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021603/calling-a-subclass-method-from-superclass

Answer (score 1):

Image that you have a 'Fruit' class and an 'Apple' class that extends Fruit. Let's also say that you can 'deCore' an Apple but not a Fruit.

Let's make a variable and set it equal to an apple:

```
Fruit f = new Apple();
```

This is like putting an apple inside of a box labeled 'Fruit'. We have no idea that there is an apple inside - we ONLY know that it is a type of fruit. Therefore, we cannot assume that it is an apple and we can only perform functions that Fruit has.

In your example, you are putting a Child object inside of a box that is labeled Parent. The Child fits - as it is a type of parent - but the program ONLY knows that it is some type of Parent. Therefore, it can only perform functions that the Parent class has.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can simple cast the class as the child

```
Parent p = new Child(); 
((Child)p).print();
```

as long as `p` is really a `Child` it will work fine otherwise you will run into exception at runtime

Comment: I'd probably consider this a code smell. You are working around (against?) the language's built-in type system.

Comment: @Robert what do you mean? If you’re overriding `equals()` for instance, you will have to cast the parameter that is of type `Object`. This is just a common practice in Java.

Comment: @Logan  Casting the object in`equals` is a special case, and I agree, it's not a great design in `equals`... given that `equals` needs to be symmetric anyway. But IMHO you shouldn't duplicate such bad design decisions into new code.

Comment: Just because you can cast doesn't mean it's good design.

Comment: We can do this casting to access it. Please check the question which I just edited. So my question is - Without casting its allow me to access the child method using an object of type parent if we define the same method in the parent class. How is this possible.