# Call non-superclass method on class

Tags: java, extends, superclass

I have class B which extends A. I declare object of A and initialise it as B. I want to call method which is not in super class.

Is there an easy way to do it? 
or I need to cast every time?

Class A //don't have access to it.

```
Class B extends A {
    methodNotInClassA();
}
```

I know this works:

```
Class C {

    A obj;
    method{
        obj = new B();
        ((B)obj).methodNotInClassA();
    }

}
```

But does something more simpler and nicer exists?

Comment: No, you have to cast every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a subclass method from superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021603/calling-a-subclass-method-from-superclass)

Comment: but what if I have a lot methods I need to call. can I create class D which extends class A. and then class B implements D. and declare object using class D ?

Comment: It's easier to just declare `obj` to be of class `B`.  So: `B obj = new B();`

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you are required to cast every single time, or you have to make a variable that is actually type `B`. You can check if a variable that is type `A` is type `B`, then make a temporary variable something like so:

```java
if(obj instanceof B) {
    B tmp = (B) obj;

    // Code using tmp instead of obj
}
```

But that is just about the prettiest you are going to get.