# How to change parameters for super class method?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to change the paint method from the Canvas class to accept an array as one of the parameters. This is what I tried:

```
    int[] array = createArray(10, 1, 10);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
    Canvas canvas = new Draw();
    canvas.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    canvas.paint(canvas.getGraphics(), array);
```

and this is the Draw class:

```
public class Draw extends Canvas
{

/**Draws the graphs
 * 
 */

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public void paint(Graphics g, int[] array)
 {
    for(int x = 0; x<array.length; x++)
    {
        g.fillRect(x, 0, 10, array[x]);
    }
 }

}
```

I tried changing the canvas object to Draw canvas = new Draw() and that didn't result in an error but it wasn't able to draw anything on the canvas when I did that. I also tried @Override but that doesn't allow me to add any extra parameters to the method.

Comment: You can't call subclass method directly from a super class object [calling a subclass method from superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021603/calling-a-subclass-method-from-superclass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Currently your `new Draw()` is declared as a `Canvas` object. If you change the declaration to `Draw canvas = new Draw();` you can call your method.</s>

Edit:
The problem is, that `paint(Graphics g)` is an internal method called by Swing, when the component will be rendered by the framework. Your `paint(Graphics g, int[] array)` method doesn't change the render process. You want to provide the parameters for creating the Drawing before `paint(Graphics g)` is called. Here is an very simple example:

```
    public class Draw extends Canvas {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int[] array;

    public Draw(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            g.fillRect(x, 0, 10, array[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you create your drawing with `Canvas draw = new Draw(array)` instead. This simple example works as long as the Drawing doesn't have to display a different array while the Gui is running (for example if a new array was created with a button press and you want to display it).

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw my last sentence but I wasn't able to draw anything on the canvas when I tried that

Comment: I think in order to actually draw anything on the canvas I need to be using the Canvas class' paint method or something

Comment: Sorry I missinterpreted what you wanted to do and edited my answer.