# Why do I get an error when I try to call a subclass method inside a baseclass method?

Tags: java

here is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        A a = new A();
        a.baseMethod();
        
    }
}

class B{
    
    public void baseMethod(){
        System.out.println("B");
        this.subMethod();   
    }
    

    
}

class A extends B{
    
    public void subMethod(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }

}
```

/MyClass.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
this.subMethod();
^
symbol: method subMethod()
1 error

I think that "this" refers to the object "a", if I put that in main it works, and class Main doesn't see class A as class B doesn't, so why can't I call the subclass method? Thank you very much

Comment: "*so why can't I call the subclass method?*" - Because there is no method `void subMethod()` defined in class `B`

Comment: Because super class does not "inherit" the members from the subclass; it's the other way around.

Comment: You can make class `B` and `subMethod` `abstract`, however.

Comment: `I think that "this" refers to the object "a"` - yes and now: in your example `this` refers to _any_ instance of class `B` or any subclass which could as well be a class `C` (that might be added to your code later and which also extends B). Delete the body of your `main()` method - this wouldn't affect the meaning of `this` at all.

Comment: Is it **guaranteed** that every subtype will provide its own implementation of `subMethod();`? No because you can write `class AA extends B{}` and it will not provide such method, so in that case what should Java do while executing `this.subMethod();`? That is why you can call subtype method if it was not defined in supertype earlier.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021603/calling-a-subclass-method-from-superclass

Answer (score 0):

Actually in this scenario, Super class (class A) can access the methods reside in base class (class B) but base class doesn't.
If you want to access the base class (class B) methods by calling object of super class (class A), you can. However, If you want to access super class (class A) methods by calling object of base class, you should have implemented the same method signature in super class.
**"this"** keyword represents the same object reference where it is called (in your case class B object).

After having method (baseMethod) with same signature in both classes, you can test it by `A a = new A();` and `A b = new B();`.

Keep coding :)