# How to call child function without casting Polymorphism Java

Tags: java, oop

Essentially I want to be able to return the health of all cards that have health or value without casting. How can I go about doing this? `Deck` is a list of cards and card can have many different sub-types. In this example I have made it really simple but my goal is to be able to extend this to many different types of cards many of which wouldn't have health.

This similar question posted here : [Calling a subclass method from superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021603/calling-a-subclass-method-from-superclass)
discuss using Casting but for example if I have 1000 different card types and only 20 of them return hp I don't want to write `if` statements for every single cast. Surely there is another solution to this problem.

```java
public class Deck {
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();

    Deck() {
        deck.add(new Item());
        deck.add(new Monster());
    }

    public ArrayList<Card> getDeck() {
        return deck;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Card {
    Card() {
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Item extends Card{
    Item() {
        super();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class Monster extends Card{
    Monster () {
        super();
    }
    
    public int getHealth() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

---

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    for (Card card : deck.getDeck()) {
        System.out.println(card.getHealth());
    }
}
```

Desired output:

```
2
```

Comment: You question doesn't say why this doesn't work. It looks like you cannot compile the program because "getHealth" doesn't exist. One way to manage this, put the method 'getHealth' on the `Card` class, then have it return a special value that signifies it is not a health. Like `-1`.

Comment: "I have 1000 different card types and only 20 of them return hp I don't want to write if statements for every single cast. " This can be accomplished by creating an interface, `Healthy { int getHealt();}` Then your 20 class that have an hp implement `Healthy` and you only check for that interface. eg one if clause/condition.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't chosen a hierarchy that actually helps you. Time to rethink this subclassing, maybe having everything be a subclass of card isn't that good an idea.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to define a `getHealth()` method in `Card` that returns an appropriate default value such as `null` or `0`.